# What's the meaning of ratio of second moment over third moment

Tags: probability, probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

The random variable $X \sim D$, what's the meaning of this term?
$$E[X^2]/E[X^3]$$
*$E[X^3]$ is the third raw moment.

Comment: It means the quotient of the second moment of $X$ and the third moment of $X$. Without furthur context, there's no more that can be told.

Comment: Thanks. So do we have any statistical meaning, like skewness, variance or something else?

Comment: What is "$D$" supposed to mean in this context?

Comment: @RobertTheTutor some arbitrary $D$istribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skewness is $$S = \frac{E[X^3]-3\mu\sigma^2-\mu^3}{\sigma^3}$$.
In the special case of $\mu = 0$, this simplifies to $E[X^3]/\sigma^3$
Meanwhile variance is $$\sigma^2 = E[X^2]-E[X]^2$$ so if $\mu=0$ that simplifies to $E[X^2]$.  So in this case, your expression
$$\frac{E[X^2]}{E[X^3]}= \frac{\sigma^2}{S\sigma^3} = \frac{1}{S\sigma}$$

I don't see what the significance of the expression is, but that is a simplified case.